# Not able to see the selected files while using filepond library

Tags: python, flask, filepond

I am trying to upload files using the filepond library. I am using python flask as backend.

Here is the code I am trying to use to get the files

```
uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file")
print("Uplaoded Files are")
print(uploaded_files)
```

This keeps returning me a null array.

The following is my html code:

```
<form action="/", method='post',  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="file" class='filepond' name='file' multiple />
</form>
```

I have also linked the file pond libraries for JS and CSS.

Please help me find whats the issue.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Do you pass multiple inputs?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to pass multiple files. I read that we need to initiate the server as specified here https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/ but I am not clear where to initiate it.

Comment: @Harshita Sorry, I didn't see that you responded. If you still have issues on this I have a solution. Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FilePond doesn't update the original input field because unfortunately that's not possible as browsers don't allow writing to the `files` or `value` property of the field. More here: https://pqina.nl/blog/the-trouble-with-editing-and-uploading-files-in-the-browser/

Therefor you either have to upload the file asynchronously (that's what the `server` property is for) or you have to encode the file as a base64 string (you can use the [file encode plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-encode/) to do this) and send it along a classic form post and then decode it on the server.